# DropDownListFor doesn't select value when first element from collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have Model, which has following fields:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Months
{
    get
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "111", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "222", Value = "2"}
        };
    }
} 
public List<TestModel> ServiceTest { get; set; }
```

Where `TestModel` has one field:

```
public string Month { get; set; }
```

Model in view has `ServiceTest = new List<ServiceTest> {new ServiceTest {Month = "2"}};`

Now, question. Why this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceTest[0].Month, Model.Months)
```

doesn't select second value. But this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceTest[0].Month, new SelectList(Model.Months, "Value", "Text", Model.ServiceTest[0].Month))
```

work correct.
I really don't understand why first expression doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I know I do not add to the discussion, but what is monthes? :->

Comment: @MichalB., oh) This example was created so quick from real project, and I don't noticed this mistake. I'll correct this later, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because the DropDownListFor helper supports only simple expressions when binding the default value. Things like `x => x.SomeProp`. In the first example you are using a complex lambda expression (Child property indexer access and yet another child property).

Your second approach is the correct way to solve this limitation of the helper.

Comment: Thank you! But I think this is so strange. Because this helper correct recognize name and id of field. And if I use other helper (e.g. TextBoxFor), it correct handle this situation. Why different behaviour?

Comment: Well, don't ask me. Ask the people that wrote this helper (Microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the first statement to work, you need to provide the List by which it is bound.

Create a property in your class:

```
public string[] SelectedMonths { get; set; }
```

Then use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMonths, new SelectList(Model.Monthes, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedMonths))
```